# Maven not copying child project dependencies

Tags: java, maven, build

I have the following plugin configured in both the parent and child projects.  The child projects end up copying the build JAR to the "target" directory, and all the third party libraries to the "target/lib" directory.  The same is not happening for the parent pom.  How do I set this up?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                    <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                    <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer> -->   
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What is child module and parent module? Can you elaborate more? copying files ca be achieved by maven resources plugin. Also maven war plugin provides feature to copy libs and resources.

Comment: Typically the parent pom doesn't have a jar file...and its uncommon for it to have its own dependencies. Can you share the rest of your parent and child pom files?

Comment: @jbunting, Vijendra, I'll just get rid of the dependency plugin on the parent since that doesn't make much sense.  I want to be able to copy the libs from all of the child project modules into a single target/lib directory.  I'll look at using the resources plugin.

Comment: Your best bet will probably be to use the maven-assembly-plugin in a new, separate child module.